# show $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{z^n\over n}$ is convergent on the unit circle

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I need to show $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{z^n\over n}$ is convergent on the unit circle  except the point $z=1$, well at $z=1$ we get our known divergent harmonic series, but I am not able to show easily the other part.